# Cmake: Exporting targets with the same name in the build tree

Tags: namespaces, cmake

let's say I have two separate cmake projects, namely:

**.../mylib1/** (CMakelists.txt)

```
project(mylib_1)
add_library(mylib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

...

**.../mylib2/** (CMakelists.txt)

```
project(mylib_2)
add_library(mylib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

Now if my app project had:

**.../app/**: (CMakelists.txt)

```
add_subdirectories(mylib1)
add_subdirectories(mylib2)
```

cmake would complain about there being two library targets with the same name. To get around this problem, I use the export functionality:

```
export(EXPORT <export-name> [NAMESPACE <namespace>] [FILE <filename>])
```

so I have something like:

```
project(mylib_1)
add_library(mylib STATIC ${SOURCES})
install(TARGETS mylib Export myExports ...)
export(myExports NAMESPACE One)
```

And the root project accessing these projects would:

```
execute_process(COMMAND cmake path/to/lib1
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib1
)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib1/myExports.cmake)
```

after that, one would use for example:

```
target_link_libraries(app mylib  One::mylib)
target_link_libraries(app mylib  Two::mylib)
```

so there is no name clash. This works fine but this requires me modifying the packages that I am trying to include. So I was wondering if there is anyway of processing these export files and assign/change their namespaces at the parent level.

The reason I am interested in this setup is if for example, I wanted to use two versions of the same library or if I had project A depending on project B and C who both depend on project D. I could leave the name space in D to be something that will be evaluated dynamically based on its hierarchy in the project: ie A-B or A-C But I don't think that's a nice way of doing that.
So is there any way of importing/processing an export file and give it a new namespace?

Comment: It's called modular code. mylib is in another repository. I have dumbed it down here for clarity.

Comment: Why do the libraries have the same name if it's not the same library?

Comment: You can still have the same "modular" code without the mess. But well, if that concept fit you needs, fine...no judge here, but you still need to change you library name though, for avoid cmake confuse of "double" trouble.

Comment: @DanMašek I thought I explained that. Library B and C are both stand-alone libraries and they both depend on D. If there was an app A that wanted to use them both, you'd run into trouble. in the example above, mylib1 and mylib2 are both the same library, but one is the one that B obtains and the other is that of C.