# Change exported target name in cmake (install alias to a target)

Tags: c++, cmake, build-system

I have a project which consists of many smaller subprojects. For ease of use we are building everything as one big project - each subproject is add_subdirectory. This way all targets are visible, we can use EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL and build only necessary dependencies, it greatly improves build times. On the other hand, it is possible to unclude some of those subprojects as a platform for another project. In this case we would want to install necessary targets. Here comes the tricky part. Target names have to be unique within the whole cmake invocation, thus out target names tend to be component_subcomponent_module. On the other hand, while we are exporting them, it makes sense to use namespace component::subcomponent. Here is a problem, it still requires using target name, so the user would have to use component::subcomponent::component_subcomponent_module. Is there a way to support both including and importing the project and using namespaced names? I want to export component_subcomponent_module as a module in component::subcomponent namespace. I understand that I can create such alias within the project but I can't find any way to change (alias) the exported name.

```
add_library(component_subcomponent_mocks ...)
install(
    TARGETS component_subcomponent_mocks
    EXPORT FindComponentSubcomponentMocks
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
)
install(
    EXPORT FindComponentSubcomponentMocks
    NAMESPACE component::subcomponent
    DESTINATION cmake
)
```

You see where it is going, imported name will become component::subcomponent::component_subcomponent_mocks.
On the other hand I can't create just:

```
add_library(mocks ...)
install(
    TARGETS mocks
    ...
}
```

If I do it this way, then adding subprojects with add_subdirectory will end up with clashing project names. One option is not to use namespaces at all. If it already has to be unique within the whole project, then what is the point of adding namespaces? I don't like this idea but this is where it is all going to.

I've seen solutions like this: [Cmake: Exporting targets with the same name in the build tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052521/cmake-exporting-targets-with-the-same-name-in-the-build-tree)
This does not solve my issues at all. I could configure it this way but the whole point of using subprojects is to avoid implementing additional layer of dependency tracking. Either we'd have to call make && make install on each (of a few hundred) dependency before proceeding to our build, or we'd have to believe that none of them has changed which leads to many mistakes. For imported projects we use this approach and it works fine but is unnecessarily slow. Just running cmake on each of them to update them in case of changes is taking a few minutes. All of this for 10 seconds of running tests you are currently developing. That's why the support for adding subprojects as subdirectories is must have for us.

In my understanding, the easiest solution would be installing target it an alias but there is no such option by default. For example:

```
install(
    TARGETS component_subcomponent_mocks
    EXPORT FindComponentSubcomponentMocks
    ...
)
install(
    EXPORT FindComponentSubcomponentMocks
    NAMESPACE component::subcomponent
    ALIAS mocks
    ...
```

This way installed target would be component::subcomponent::mocks and target used by add_subdirectory would be component_subcomponent_mocks which I can easily aliast to the same namespaced version. Everything would be neat and consistent except it is not supported by default. Is there any alternative to it?

There were similar but not detailed questions to this, all without a particular answer.
[Change name of exported target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598403/change-name-of-exported-target)
[cmake install xxxTargets.cmake with a different name from the original target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704087/cmake-install-xxxtargets-cmake-with-a-different-name-from-the-original-target)

The whole problem is that I have to keep my target names unique, so they already include their "namespace" in the name and including it once again seems to be pointless.

Comment: "I have to keep my target names unique, so they already include their "namespace" in the name and including it once again seems to be pointless." - If you don't want to add `component::subcomponent::` prefix... then do not add it. Why do you specify `NAMESPACE` if you don't want a prefix?

Comment: That's basically the solution, don't use namespaces and replace it with very long variable names. Cmake seems to be lacking support for namespaces in very big projects. It also explains problems many people have with adding dependencies as subprojects. If two of them defined the same target, then it won't work. You have to modify your buildsystem to build and install dependencies before you proceed with your part of the project. I wanted to avoid this and still keep nice and consistent look of namespace.

Comment: @Tsyvarev For now I took intermediate solution. I use shorter but still unique (user defined names) and namespace is defined based on the project. There's more risk of name clashing while adding subproject (eg. audio::routing::client and conn::dns::client) so I'll add notes to keep it fairly descriptive (audio::RoutingClient, conn::DnsClient) and still use increased isolation with namespace in case the project is imported by another project. Essentially, ensure uniqueness within our projects and reserve namespaces between other master projects.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your question. If you want to ask about namespaces in **original** (non-*exported*) target names, then why do you talk about exported one? If you can handle original target names, and ask about exported ones, then I don't understand your comments. "Cmake seems to be lacking support for namespaces in very big projects." - What do you mean by "support for namespases"? Ability to **externally** wrap a project with namespace? How many **scripting** languages do you know which support that feature? CMake is a **scripting** language, unlike to C++, Java, C#, etc.

Comment: "don't use namespaces and replace it with very long variable names" - you could avoid using long **target** names in the project itself. E.g., at the top of the project you could define `NS` variable - `set(NS "<component>_<subcomponent>_")` and use it for every target in the project: `add_library(${NS}mocks ...)`, `install(TARGETS ${NS}mocks ...)`. Because of scoping rules for variables in CMake, you don't need to bother about several projects which use the same `NS` variable: inside the project the variable has the project-specific value.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Cmake supports exported targets namespaces, so you can't say that it does not have the concept of namespaces. If you can import libX from two packages and refer to one as firstPackage::X, the other one as secondPackage::X, then it is there.
The question is mainly about consistency, how can I make it work with imported projects and subprojects (subdirectories) using the same naming convention. First option is not to use namespaces. Then why would anyone use them? I don't have a problem with defining libraries, that's all done in functions. The problem is referring to them from others.

Comment: "The question is mainly about consistency, how can I make it work with imported projects and subprojects (subdirectories) using the same naming convention." - Hm. so which naming convention do you want? A convention `component::subcomponent::lib` looks nice, but CMake disallow `::` in names for normal (non-IMPORTED) targets. But both IMPORTED and non-IMPORTED targets could use a convention `component_subcomponent_lib`. A convention could also be `component-subcomponent-lib` or `component.subcomponent.lib`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Basically any convention not using namespaces will work, it's just kind of counterintuitive that people use namespaces for exported targets and here you will have dots or underscores. I ended up mixing both solutions. Target is ```SubcomponentLib```, it is aliased as ```component::SubcomponentLib``` and also installed in namespace ```component```. Still ```SubcomponentLib``` has to be unique within all subprojects but it's less risk than having multiple targets ```Lib```. Most of all, it is used with the same namespace inside and outside.

Comment: It seems that CMake reserves **colon-separated** namespaces only for **packages**. When you use a package, you have no access to its `CMakeLists.txt`, no access to its build rules, etc. - the package is **already built**. As far as I understand, this is similar to Java "namespaces": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249357/difference-between-namespace-in-c-sharp-and-package-in-java. But a term "namespace" doesn't mean using only a colon-separation.  For subprojects (which are not packages!) you could use any other naming convention and refer to it as a "namespace".

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well, you can still create aliases with namespaces. It would be nice if targets supported namespaces as well. AFAIR the target name has to be unique but you can rename generated object by changing ```OUTPUT_NAME```. It would be useful if you could also rename the target that will be installed in install command (eg. install ```my_component_lib``` as ```lib``` and export it in namespace ```my::component::```. It works the other way around. I actually made a mistake by setting export namespace to ```my::component``` which resulted in ```my::componentLibName```.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So the functionality is there, the namespace is just text prepended to all exported targets when they are imported so additional rule to change target name should be possible. Anyways, it's not available, so the topic can probably be closed as impossible or wait until such functionality arrives.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [EXPORT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_NAME.html) property on your targets.
The following setup ensures consistent names (e.g. component::subcomponent::target) both in cmake superprojects as well as in exported configurations.

```
add_library(component_subcomponent_mylib ...)
set_property(TARGET component_subcomponent_mylib PROPERTY EXPORT_NAME mylib)
add_library(component::subcomponent::mylib ALIAS component_subcomponent_mylib)

install(TARGETS component_subcomponent_mylib
    EXPORT FindComponentSubcomponentTargets
    DESTINATION lib
)

install(EXPORT FindComponentSubcomponentTargets
    DESTINATION cmake
    NAMESPACE component::subcomponent::
)
```